# Synchronized object vs. unsynchronized object

Tags: multithreading, object, optimization, compiler-construction, synchronization

> The statement "unsynchronized Objects typically perform better than
>   synchronized ones" isn't always true anymore with modern compilers.

This is an assertion I've heard several times today. I've got two different interpretations of  the assertion:

1. With the advances of modern compilers, the overhead imposed on synchronized object can be so small that it can just be ignored. If this is the case, how do modern compilers achieve this goal?
2. There are cases where synchronized object and unsynchronized object perform equally well or even cases where synchronized object performs better than unsynchronized one. I don't think it's possible, but who knows?

Comment: Where who, and in which context did you hear this?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Please Google the assertion in quotes, you may get several hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One case is when a  compiler can statically determine that an object is never accessed by more than one thread via *inter-thread escape analysis*. Then the compiler can initialize the "vtable" (or whatever is the appropriate method dispatch mechanism) with an un-synchronized version of methods.

PS. The above is with regard to the first interpretation of the statement.